# Problem with partitions while installing Manjaro from Live USB

Tags: partition, system-installation, manjaro

I created a live USB using Rufus (with DD) using this version from the offical page:
`manjaro-xfce-18.0.2-stable-x86_64.iso`

I use a Lenovo Yoga 720. I disabled secure boot and fast boot in the bios.

Everything worked fine, but when I wanted to install Manjaro using the gui, the program would not let me choose a hard drive, let alone a partition to install to.

Does anyone know what my problem is?

[image: Can't select storage device]

Comment: Running into exactly the same problem. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: No sadly not, I went with a Kubuntu installation and it worked flawlessly

Comment: I ended up fixing it, not sure what particular thing fixed it though. I changed the IDE drive jumpers from master to slave, I reformatted it, and I made sure that the Live CD (USB) wasn't mounting it on startup